# Suppose you have 5 blueberry pancakes, 2 banana pancakes, and 2 chocolate chip pancakes. How many ways can you stack the pancakes by flavour?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose you have 5 blueberry pancakes,  2 banana pancakes,  and 2 chocolate chip pancakes.  How many ways can you stack the pancakes by flavour?

Comment: And what did you try? Show your attempts.

Comment: (5c3)(2c2)(2c1)(9!)=7257600?

Comment: C representing nCr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your full stack will be 9 pancakes high. So where will the blueberry pancakes be? You have $9\choose 5$ possibilities to choose their position (because you cannot distinguish two blueberry pancakes from one another). So now you have only 4 places left. You have now $4\choose 2$ possibilities to choose positions for the two banana pancakes and the two chocolate chip pancakes will have to take the last 2 remaining places in your stack. So the total amount of ways to stack the pancakes by flavour is $n={9\choose 5}*{4\choose 2} = 756$

Comment: Oh okay that makes more sense now,  thank you so much :)